# unable to get date value from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, date, undefined

I am getting 'undefined' date value while trying to get date from JSON object.
Following is my code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var dtUnavlStr=${jsonArray};
  var obj = JSON.stringify(dtUnavlStr);
  console.log("obj<<<<<<<"+obj);
  var dtUnavailable= new Array();
  for(var i=0;i<dtUnavlStr.length;i++){
      console.log("date["+i+"]========"+obj.bkng_t_date);
      dtUnavailable[i]=obj[i].bkng_t_date;
      console.log("ARRAYDATA>>>>>"+dtUnavailable[i]);
   }
```

});

And here is my console log.

```
    obj<<<<<<<[{"bkng_t_date":"25/07/2020"},{"bkng_t_date":"26/07/2020"}]
    date[0]========undefined
    ARRAYDATA>>>>>undefined
    date[1]========undefined
    ARRAYDATA>>>>>undefined
```

Any and all help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `obj` is holding string(`var obj = JSON.stringify(dtUnavlStr);`), you can't access `bkng_t_date `from `obj` which is a string

Comment: Thank you so much. Tried without the stringify. It worked.

Comment: @NazneenShaikh, if you have solved your problem, you should write an answer so that others who may arrive here in the future can see what you did to solve your problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a simple misunderstanding that *JSON.stringify* produces a string, not an object, so is unlikely to help others.

Comment: Hi, trying to execute(stringify) was my last desperate attempt after trying everything possibile to get the code working.  Actually when I removed the stringify statement also my code did not work.Then I added console stmts for every variable in jsp and servlet. and I realised I have added object to JSON as "bkng_t_data" instead of "bkng_t_date" and so while retrieving the value it returned undefined.  But since that was not part of the problem I stated here.  I updated stating that removing stringify worked. @RobG it was indeed a simple misunderstanding and you can close the topic.  Thank you